# Is semaphore an IPC mechanism?

Tags: ipc, semaphore

Is semaphore an IPC mechanism?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, under many platforms semaphores can synchronize across processes.  You would use "named" semaphores for this -- multiple processes access the object via a name, similar to filesystem objects.

In POSIX, you can create named semaphores via `sem_open()`.  For unamed semaphores, if the second parameter to `sem_init()` is nonzero, it can be interprocess, though I'm not sure exactly how an unnamed interprocess semaphore is supposed to work.

Note that on some systems these functions may fail with `ENOSYS` if interprocess semaphores aren't supported (for example OpenBSD).

In Windows, you can create named semaphores via `CreateSemaphore()` as @sergiom has mentioned.

Comment: Since since version 5.4 (Nov 2013) OpenBSD has [named semaphores](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sem_open&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html). See [this blog post](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/sem-open-named-semaphores)

Comment: Re: "I'm not sure exactly how an unnamed interprocess semaphore is supposed to work": You can put the semaphore in shared memory. Also, if you create an unnamed interprocess semaphore in normal memory and then call `fork()`, you've got IPC between the parent and child processes. In neither case, of course, is an unnamed semaphore discoverable in the way that a named semaphore is. But you generally only need a semaphore if there's some other relationship between the processes, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the operating system

In Windows named semaphores can be accessed between processes using the CreateSemaphore() and OpenSemaphore() functions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Actually Semaphore is a synchronisation tool but it is counted as an IPC bcoz it is accessed by more than 1 process

Answer (score 1):

> POSIX semaphores can be unnamed or
>   named. Unnamed semaphores are
>   allocated in process memory and
>   initialized. Unnamed semaphores might
>   be usable by more than one process,
>   depending on how the semaphore is
>   allocated and initialized. [...]

Would you like to know [more](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5137/6mba5vq4s?a=view)?