# why semaphore is considered as a IPC?

Tags: linux, ipc, semaphore

In all books semaphore is listed under IPC mechanism?
Why is it like that?
Because what I know is that semaphore is used for synchronization.

I have read one similar question in this forum but, that didn't cleared the doubt.

Comment: "[Semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) is used for synchronization" between different process or threads, that is why it is considered as a IPC.

Comment: But it does not facilitate to transfer data through it , right?
Just because two or more process in order to synchronize need semaphore,, so its called IPC?

Comment: IPC stands for 'Inter-Process Communication', and 'Communication' means to transfer *information* between processes, when to do some actions (synchronization) is the information to be transfered between the processes.

Comment: @VirendraKumar Read about [Concurrency control mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) using semaphore-variable is a technique (simplest) using that you can impose control over execution of cocurant processes

Comment: What books have you read?
*All*?

Comment: I have already written in the question that i have read some questions similar to this in Stackoverflow , but i was not satisfied with the answers so i have asked again @Dominic kexel

Answer (score 3):

[man page for sem_overview](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) tells (with description how to do it) :

> POSIX semaphores allow processes and threads to synchronize their actions.

therefore semaphores can be used for interprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

well in linux there are basically two types of semaphores

```
named semaphores
unnamed semaphores
```

and I think here unnamed semaphores is basically known for IPC mechanism plus locking mechanism both.and named one are only used for locking mechanism

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243205/is-semaphore-an-ipc-mechanism) can be useful

Comment: You are right but when we read IPC in Linux books , this topic is given under both Synchronization and IPC, so i asked

Comment: @VirendraKumar I made some correction check again

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because of named semaphores.
There are two types of semaphores, named and unnamed.

Usually named semaphores are used for processes synchronization, whereas unnamed semaphores are used for threads synchronization.

[This *Multithreaded Programming Guide*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5137/sync-39/index.html) says

> Named semaphores are like process-shared semaphores, except that named
>   semaphores are referenced with a pathname rather than a pshared value.
>   Named semaphores are sharable by several processes.

*It is possible to share unnamed semaphores (with child processes for example) among process but it is not common.